# How to emit optimisation reports using Apple clang 3.5?

Tags: c++, clang

According to the documentation, clang supports [options to emit optimisation reports](http://llvm.org/releases/3.5.0/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-emit-optimization-reports):

> 1. When the pass makes a transformation (-Rpass).
> 2. When the pass fails to make a transformation (-Rpass-missed).
> 3. When the pass determines whether or not to make a transformation (-Rpass-analysis).

They provide the following example command line:

> `$ clang -O2 -Rpass=inline code.cc -o code`

When I try this, I get an error:

```
$ clang src/test/tests.cpp -Rpass=inline    
clang: error: unknown argument: '-Rpass=inline'
scons: *** [build/test/tests.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

My clang version is:

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Is this option not available on Mac OS? Is the documentation erroneous? Or am I doing it wrong? If so, how to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for Debian clang-3.5.0-6, so this is probably Apple clang restriction.

```
% clang++ -O2 -Rpass=inline foo.cpp
foo.cpp:11:2: remark: _ZN1CC2Ev inlined into main [-Rpass=inline]
        P* p = new C();
        ^
% clang --version
Debian clang version 3.5.0-6 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)
Target: i386-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Yes, this is indeed an Apple thing. After switching to a release from http://llvm.org it works as documented.